# HTML/ GitHub Hosted Website, jpg images not showing up

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I am hosting a website through Github pages and I can only get png images to appear. I need to use jpg for my index.html since I can't compress the png's any more to stop the site from lagging when loading the images.

I have checked all cases and spelling, and they are matching up.

Answer (score 1):

http://stvnduong.com/images/about-min.JPG is not the same as http://stvnduong.com/images/about-min.jpg.

Filenames are case-sensitive on Github (and most webservers you'll encounter).

Comment: I've changed that one back to .jpg but it still won't appear. I'm wondering why png would simply work yet jpg wont xP

Comment: @macNcheeseThisNThat Your `.png` is working because you've used the same case in the filename and the HTML. I'm very dubious that fixing the case didn't work, considering I can access the `.jpg` version. Why did you censor your website in the edited question?